# Space being removed between two ASP expression codes

Tags: asp.net, string, variables, asp-classic

I'm new to ASP and have been tasked to update a file by a client.  When I try to "echo" two variables with a space between them the space is being removed.  Any ideas why?

Here are two examples:

```
<%
    Dim variable1, variable2
    variable1 = "Hello"
    variable2 = "there"
%>
<p><%= variable1 %> <%= variable2 %></p>
```

or

```
<p><% Response.write( variable1 ) %> <%= Response.write( variable2 ) %></p>
```

This writes: `<p>Hellothere</p>` without the space in between the two words.  Am I doing something wrong? or is this normal to ASP?

I've resorted to using the following, but am having a hard time believing that content outside of the <% %> would be getting removed.

```
<% Response.Write( variable1 & " " & variable2 ) %>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Stick an `&nbsp;` in between. It is normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. It's one of those things. Whitespace before or after code blocks (`<%...%>`) is considered part of the HTML document but whitespace *between* consecutive code blocks is ignored. You have a couple options:

1. Insert `&nbsp;` between (explicit whitespace):

   ```
   <p><%= variable1 %>&nbsp;<%= variable2 %></p>
   ```
2. Write the full tag in a single ASP context:

   ```
   Response.Write "<p>" & variable1 & " " & variable2 & "</p>"
   ' or
   <p><%= variable1 & " " & variable2 %></p>
   ```

Comment: Bear in mind that `&nbsp;` is **non-breaking** white space. So there could be strange things happening if you string lots together.

Comment: It is indeed "one of those things".  It can also catch you out if you're adding a variable to an SQL query - eg you sometimes need to use `...where var = "& var &" order by...` rather than `...where var = "& var &"order by...`

Comment: If  you want a regular space (and not a non-breaking space) you can insert &#32; between the code blocks: <%= variable1 %>&#32;<%= variable2 %>